# how to sort list and return using Flutter and Dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am new to development.
I am having issue with existing code I code from my fellow developer. They guy sorted a list using a model and compare the version but it only returns one element of the list. This is my code

```
static NavigationalCatalogDto getLatestVersionCatalog(
    List<NavigationalCatalogDto> navigationalCatalogList) {
      navigationalCatalogList.sort((b, a) => a.version!.compareTo(b.version!));
      return navigationalCatalogList[0];
    }
```

I want to return all the items inside the list after sorting. please help me

Comment: Is removing the array still return one element?

Comment: if I remove the List then I can't sort it and if I don't give index number I got "A value of type 'List<NavigationalCatalogDto>' can't be returned from the method 'getLatestVersionCatalog' because it has a return type of 'NavigationalCatalogDto'"

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove the [0] so it does not select the first element. Remember to change the return type of the method as well.

```
static List<NavigationalCatalogDto> getLatestVersionCatalog(
List<NavigationalCatalogDto> navigationalCatalogList) {
  return navigationalCatalogList.sort((b, a) => a.version!.compareTo(b.version!));
}
```